# Two types of electric field

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electric-current, electromagnetic-induction

My textbook mentions that electric field produced by electric charge and that produced by changing magnetic field are different in nature.
After searching from various sources I found that **electric field produced by changing magnetic field is not conservative while that produced by electric charge is conservative.**
Another statement I found out was 
**line integral of electrostatic field between any two points is potential difference while line integral of induced electric field between any two points is electromotive force**

Now combining the two can I say that potential difference is conservative while electromotive force is not conservative? Is it a right conclusion or statement written above are wrong ? Also it would be great if more difference between the two types of electrical field are pointed out.
Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

> Now combining the two can I say that potential difference is
> conservative while electromotive force is not conservative?

No, you can't say that. "Conservative" is an attribute of the electric field and not of its line integrals.

#### Long answer:

It is true that some electric fields are conservative while others are not. In particular, all electrostatic fields (that is, fields generated by non-accelerating charges) are conservative. A conservative field is such that its line integral on a closed path is always zero:

$$
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s} = 0.
$$

This relation can be also written in a local form by means of Stokes' theorem:

$$
\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = 0.
$$

A consequence of being conservative is that it is possible to define a potential difference between two points $A$ and $B$ which is independent of the path chosen to connect them. In other words, the quantity

$$
\Delta V_{AB} \equiv \int_A^B \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s}
$$

can be written as the difference between a function evaluated in $A$ and $B$, that is

$$
\Delta V_{AB} = V(A) - V(B).
$$

Here is the important bit: the line integral can *always* be computed, even when the electric field is not conservative. However, in this case the final result depends on the path over which the line integral is computed, and hence no function $V$ (the electrostatic potential) can be defined.

The electromotive force, on the other hand, is defined as

$$
f_{\rm em} = \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{s},
$$

which, by definition, can be different from zero *only* if $\vec{E}$ is not conservative. However, note that the closed path integral above might be zero for some paths even when $\vec{E}$ is not conservative.

Comment: > *"the potential difference can always be computed as the line integral of the electric field, even when the latter is not conservative."* the line integral can be indeed always computed, but if the field is not conservative, it is incorrect to call it potential difference (or voltage).

Comment: Yes, you are of course right. Thanks for the comment! I have updated my answer.

Comment: You're welcome. There is still a minor pet peeve of mine: you write that no function $V$ can be defined. However, in practice $V$ is used even then. This is possible because it is defined through the electrostatic part of the electric field, not total electric field. For example, we talk about voltage on a coil/solenoid in AC circuits, and this can be measured, although the integral $\int \mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf s$ has no single value.